# How to get the connected objects within a collection in an array in Mongoose MongoDb NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, hapi.js

I am new to NodeJS and I am using NodeJS Framework HapiJs. I have parent-child schema of a Model "Elements" in which parent and child belongs to the same collection. The schema is similar to following:

```
var mschema = new Schema({
    autoIncrementId: { type: Number,unique: true,index:true,sparse:true},
    elementName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    elementCanvasId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    parentId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: false,
        ref: "Elements",
    },
    parentCanvasId: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
});

var modules = Mongoose.model('Elements', mschema);
```

here `elementCanvasId` is generated at client side. And `parentCanvasId` is a reference to `elementCanvasId` of the parent element. Also its not necessary that every element will have a parent. Now based on `elementCanvasId` of element I wanna fetch all the elements that comes under hierarchy(i.e all its children elements and then children's subchildren and then their's subchildren and so on.) of that element in a Single Dimensional Array. I cannot use `Schema.Types.ObjectId` for this purspose as I only have to use `elementCanvasId` which is generated at client's side only. So, can someone help me out to get it done. Any kind of help is hugely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **$graphLookup**. As $graphLookup performs a recursive search on a collection.

```
Elements.aggregate([{ $graphLookup : {
  from : 'elements', // MongoDB collection name not mongoose schema name
  startWith : '$parentCanvasId', //it is expression which can include can include field paths and system variables, literals, expression objects etc.
  connectFromField : 'elementCanvasId',
  as : 'children'
} }])
```

If you want to fetch element hierarchy for only one element then you need to use **$match** in aggregation pipeline

```
Elements.aggregate([{ $match : { autoIncrementId : '1'  } }, { $graphLookup : {
  from : 'elements', // MongoDB collection name not mongoose schema name
  startWith : '$parentCanvasId', 
  connectFromField : 'elementCanvasId',
  as : 'children'
} }])
```

Note : *autoIncrementId : 1* is the condition by which you can fetch the result for single element

Comment: Thanks a ton my friend. You just saved my day It worked superbly. Also appreciated help from Peter Grainger who gave me a good direction to work with.

Comment: Welcome @DimpalSingh

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `$graphLookup`, however it can only be used from version 3.4+, it gets quite complicated

For full details see https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/

```
Elements.aggregate( [
   {
      $graphLookup: {
         from: "elements",
         startWith: "$parentCanvasId",
         connectFromField: "parentCanvasId",
         connectToField: "elementCanvasId",
         as: "elementHierarchy"
      }
   }
] )
```

Comment: Can you please write down the Mongoose syntax to execute this mongodb query?

Comment: done, you just run aggregate on the schema, also I'm assuming the collection with the parentCanvasId is named elements

Comment: Yes Both parentCanvasId and elementCanvasId belongs to "Elements" Collection. Also what exactly do we need to pass in "startWith" field. is it supposed be value of the id of the element or just like you have written "$parentCanvasId"

Comment: yeah, just $parentCanvasId, see https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/ for all the options

Comment: the reason it is there twice is that you might have multiple connectFromField terms if you have multiple child references

Comment: Okay. But doing so is fetching hierarchy for every object/document of that collection. And I want to fetch hierarchy starting from a specific elementCanvasId only

Comment: You need to use $match for fetching hierarchy for specific elementCanvasId. See my answer for more details